# modifying every other element's class inside while loop

Tags: functions

```
<?php 
    $homePosts = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5                       
    ));

    while ($homePosts->have_posts()) {
      $homePosts->the_post(); ?>

    <section class="align-right>
        <div class="content">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>                                 
        </div>
    </section>

<?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

The above code is part of my `front-page.php`. I am trying to modify the class that is in `<section class="align-*****">`, so that the 1st, 3rd, and 5th sections have `class='align-left'` and the 2nd, and 4th sections have `class='align-right'`.

What would be the best approach to modify the class values within a WordPress loop? Would I need to write my own function in `functions.php`? Use jQuery? Is there a WP function that can help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$homePosts = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5                       
));

$count = 1;

while ($homePosts->have_posts()) {
  $homePosts->the_post(); 

    if ( $count % 2 == 0 ) {
        $class = 'right';
    } else {
        $class = 'left';
    }

?>

<section class="align-<?php echo $class; ?>" >
    <div class="content">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>                                 
    </div>
</section>

<?php 
$count++;

} wp_reset_postdata(); 

?>
```

You can try this code

Comment: You can use `$homePosts->current_post` which stores the index of the current item in the loop. The first element of the collection has index `0`.